# How to return immediately to the list of questions after committing an edit/suggest?

Tags: support, feature-request

After committing the suggest I would like to be able to go "back" to the list of questions **immediately** - but every "back" action of my browser takes me first back to the edit window, then to the edited version ("only visible to me") and only **then** back to the list.
No big issue but slightly annoying - how do others handle that situation? Just press "back" three times?

My current workflow when editing is the following (which *might* be suboptimal anyway :-))

- I open [the questions list](https://askubuntu.com/questions)
- open the first question to see if it needs anything
- if not I press **back** to return to the same place
- else I click **edit**, ...., commit the suggestion
- now I'd like to return to the same place in the list where I started, like I do when not editing the question

**You got me thinking!** I just might start the *edit process* in a **new tab**, which would remedy my current annoyance - No need for anybody to create anything :-))

**Post Scriptum**
After having gained the "edit privilege" the mentioned annoying behavior completely vanishes - that means: most here couldn't experience what I was talking about - please keep that in mind when someone else asks something similar in the future :-))

Comment: Just click on the "Ask Ubuntu" button in the corner maybe?  I guess it depends on where you were.

Comment: @iSeth well, not quite - I want to return to that place in the list where I started :-)

Comment: Ah, that would be a lot more difficult :/

Comment: Could a user script do this...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing how you added the answer to your edit, I'm turning my comment into an answer then:

The general consensus on user experience with multi-page-lists is as follows:

> You look through a list in order to find either **one**, or **multiple** items.
>
> - If you want **multiple** items, open them in **multiple windows/tabs**.
> - If you want **only one**, why do you want to go back to the point in the list at which you were before?

So, the "solution" to your problem is more or less to do as is assumed and use the tabs features. Open a new tab for every question you want to read, rather than using the tab in which you have the list opened.

As Eliah pointed out in a comment, excellent choices for speedy tab-opening are <kbd>MOUSE2</kbd> (a.k.a. Middle Mouse Button) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>MOUSE0</kbd> (a.k.a. Mouse Click).

That way, you retain the tab with the list and don't need to go back **and** you get your question opened.

A slight side note: Using the *Back* button is largely discouraged nowadays, due to dynamic content and forms. When going back, you reload a page that you should not get to in this direction. Thus, some pages may work, others may not. Sometimes the browser warns you, sometimes it just tells you "Nope."

**Simply put:** Don't use it. If you want to go back to some earlier point *regularly*, keep that point in a tab.